# Laravel Database Query

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I am trying to write a MySQL select query using Laravel's Database Query Builder as follows:

Select all projects where the project's `author_id` equals the user's `id` , or where the project's `group_id` equals a `group_id` that the user is assigned to.

For example:

User 1 is in group 24. There are 3 projects in group 7. User 1 wants to see all of the projects from that group.

### Database Tables:

**users**

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
```

**projects**

```
+-----------+----------+
| author_id | group_id |
+-----------+----------+
```

**groups**

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
```

**groups_users_are_assigned**

```
+---------+----------+
| user_id | group_id |
+---------+----------+
```

Any help on how to do this correctly in a single query would be amazing.
Thanks!

Comment: `Lavarel` or `Laravel` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A don't want to create a test enviroment for this query, but according to my knowledge, this should work:

```
DB::table('projects')
    ->leftJoin('groups_users_are_assigned', 'projects.group_id', '=', 'groups_users_are_assigned.group_id')
    ->where('author_id', '=', $userId)
    ->orWhere('groups_users_are_assigned.user_id', '=', $userId)
    ->get()
```

Comment: Excellent - thank you, works perfectly. The 'orWhere' needed the equals operator passed as the second argument, and $userId as third.